# How to iterate over DOM?

Tags: reactjs

How to iterate over DOM element inputbox. I want to loop through each `<input/>`. I get error `this.refs.inputBoxes.map is not a function`

```
componentDidMount: function(){
  this.refs.inputBoxes.map(function(e, i){
  console.log(e)
})



render: function () {
  return (
    <div>
      <input className= "iB" type="checkbox" ref="inputBoxes"/> 
      <input className= "iB" type="checkbox" ref="inputBoxes"/>
      <input className= "iB" type="checkbox" ref="inputBoxes"/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I still get error saying it's not a function after changing to this:    `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.inputBoxes).map(function(e, i){
      console.log(e)
    })`

Comment: Please read what `ReactDOM.findDOMNode` expects. You have to pass in the component itself (`this` in your case), and since that gives you the root dom node, you have get its children.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's really no reason to not just use `document.querySelectorAll`

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input.iB');
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    console.log(inputs[i]);
  }
}


render: function () {
  return (
    <div>
      <input className= "iB" type="checkbox" ref="inputBoxes"/> 
      <input className= "iB" type="checkbox" ref="inputBoxes"/>
      <input className= "iB" type="checkbox" ref="inputBoxes"/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Ugh! There are plenty of reasons not to use `querySelectorAll`, what if there are other input boxes on the page? What if there are two of these components on the page? Every query will always return all the inputs on the page @Deke Please do not accept this as the correct answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41389208/227299 has a much better way to find your DOM nodes

Comment: Updated to use the class as well.

Comment: Another issue, what if there are 2 of the given component?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are simply overriding the previously set `this.refs.inputBoxes` field. I don't think that automatically becomes an array if you set the same ref for multiple components. However you could give a ref to your container:

```
<div ref={e => this._inputBoxContainer = e}>
  <input className= "iB" type="checkbox"/> 
  <input className= "iB" type="checkbox"/>
  <input className= "iB" type="checkbox"/>
</div>
```

And in your mount method simply access the children! If you want to perform array operations on it you will have to convert it to an array since it's an `HtmlCollection`.:

```
componentDidMount() {
  Array.from(this._inputBoxContainer.children).map(e => {
    console.log(e)
  })
}
```